# upload multiple jars to repo in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build

In my build.gradle file, I am creating multiple jars with different compilation for each using the following:

**build.gradle**

```
task devJar(Type: Jar){
  baseName = 'quickjar'
  version = project.version
  classifier = 'dev'
  from('src/resources'){
    include' dev.properties
    }
  from(sourceSets.main.output){
    include '**/*.*'
    }
}

build.finalizedBy(devJar, anotherJar, anotherJar, uploadArchives)

uploadArchives{
    repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
        repository(url: uri('../../repo'))
    }
  }
}
```

This however is only creating one jar file in my repo and not all the jars within my build file. How might I achieve uploading multiple jars to the repo that are created within this build file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding your `devJar` task as an `artifact`?

```
task devJar(Type: Jar) {
    //...
}

task qaJar(Type: Jar) {
    //...
}

task prodJar(Type: Jar) {
    //...
}

artifacts {
    archives devJar, qaJar, prodJar
}

uploadArchives {
    //...
}
```